# Async/Await confusion in JS

Tags: javascript

I was learning asynchrony in JS and came across Async/Await. Then, I came across this code:

```
function scaryClown() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function msg() {
  const msg = await scaryClown();
  console.log('Message:', msg);
}

msg(); // Message:  <-- after 2 seconds
```

Thus, I have questions on the above code. Firstly, how can async function msg() return message value if the function itself returns only undefined Promise, that is, the function does not explicitly use return keyword. Secondly, does await returns Promise or value itself having been unwrapped from Promise?

Comment: It isn't returning `undefined`, it *is* using the `return` keyword, to return a Promise, and that Promise resolves to the `` string

Comment: Be aware that the function already returns when it meets `await`. The  `return` statement will be executed later, asynchronously and only serves to resolve the promise that function had returned earlier on when it executed `await`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, hi, so does "await scaryClown();" return unwrapped  from a promise and not promise itself? If so, then msg will contain  ok but according to my research if async function does not explicitly use return keyword in itself then there will be returned promise that resolves to undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function msg() {
  const msg = await scaryClown();
  console.log('Message:', msg);
}
```

await resolves promise and return resolved value. so above code with then can be written like below. hope this makes you understand async await.

```
function msg() {
  scaryClown().then(msg => {
    console.log('Message:', msg);
  });    
}
```

Comment: hi Amit, so await returns unwrapped  from a promise, that is, await does not return promise but just ? Is that true?

Comment: await resolves your promise and assign resolved value to msg variable.

Comment: so yes await doesn't return promise, it returns resolved value. in your case joker emoji.

Comment: ok Amit, the last thing, if msg constant contains joker emoji then why if we invoke msg() function, it console logs emoji. I mean is it true that if we do not explicitly use return in async function then the return value is promise that resolves to undefined?

Comment: so when you make any function async by adding async keyword it wraps that function in promise and that promise is returned. so if you don't return anything from your async function, returned promise is resolved with undefined.

Comment: *"await resolves promise"*: this is plain wrong information.

Comment: @trincot maybe my wording is wrong but eventually await wait for returned promise to be resolved and then assign resolved value to a variable if there is an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
function scaryClown() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

The above function is a function which returns a promise when it is called, but will only be resolved after 2 seconds.

```
async function msg() {
  const msg = await scaryClown();
  console.log('Message:', msg);
}
```

the above function is asynchronous function which awaits for the promise to be resolved (in your case, after 2 seconds) and then only the console.log() triggers.

**Note**: any lines of code below the function msg() gets executed irrespective of the promise and the asynchronous function.

Running code snippet

```js
function scaryClown() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('');
        }, 2000);
      });
    }

async function msg() {
  console.log(scaryClown()); // try without await, so it will not wait for the result and prints first, but an unresolved promise
  const msg = await scaryClown(); // actual result which is resolved, because we awaited
  console.log('Message:', msg); // Prints once the resolved value is available.
}



msg(); //executes first but only prints the value once it is resolved.

console.log('I will continue executing irrespective of async func msg()');
```

Comment: hi, Is it true that msg() returns undefined wrapped by promise?

Comment: The asynchronous function message does not return anything, inside, it just waits (await) for the promise to be resolved from the scaryClown function, and once it is resolved (in your case 2 seconds), the vaiable msg will get the value and then it is console logged

Answer (score 0):

### This is what happens:

When the `async` function (i.e. `msg`) is invoked, it creates a promise object (let's call it P), which it will return when it deals with an `await` expression. `scaryClown()` executes, which sets the timer and returns yet another promise object; let's call it Q. Then `await` is processed: at that moment the function returns the promise P. This promise is *not* resolved at that moment; it is pending.

If then there is any other code that followed the call of `msg()`, then that is executed like would be the case after any function call. Execution continues until the call stack is empty.

Then, some time later the timer event that was scheduled by `scaryClown()` will fire, and the corresponding promise Q resolves. Because this promise Q was in an `await` expression, this resolution triggers a restoration of the execution context of `msg()`, where the `await` expression is now evaluated to be Q's resolved value, i.e. "".

The variable `msg` gets this value assigned, and it is displayed with `console.log`. Then the function completes, in this particular case without any explicit `return`.  Remember that the function had already *returned*, so this is not really a normal return: code execution really *ends* here, as there is nothing on the call stack. This makes the promise P resolve. If there had been an explicit `return` statement, with a value, the promise P would have been resolved with *that* value. But since there is no such `return` statement in your example, promise P resolves with `undefined`.

As you don't do anything with the value returned by `msg()`, you don't really see what it returns. If you would have done:

```
msg().then(console.log);
```

... you would have seen `undefined` in the console.

### Your questions:

> how can `async function msg()` return message value if the function itself returns only undefined Promise, that is, the function does not explicitly use `return` keyword.

The `msg()` call does currently *not* provide you with the message value. Instead it uses `console.log` to *output* it, but that is not the value *returned* by `msg()`. The returned value is a promise. Even if it had an explicit `return` keyword, it would still not make `msg()` return something else than a promise. The only difference would be what *value* that promise would eventually resolve to.

> does `await` returns Promise or value itself having been unwrapped from Promise?

`await` does two things at two different moments in time. First it makes the function *return* to the caller. Then, when the promise that it awaits resolves, it makes the function continue to run again, and `await` represents at that moment the promised *value*, which can therefore be assigned to a variable (or used in another way).

I personally don't use the verb "unwrapped" when talking about promises. But yes, the expression `await promise` evaluates (asynchronously) to the value that `promise` fulfils to.